# How to access client's appData folder in node.js

Tags: node.js, dropbox

I want to be able to find out if the client system has a dropbox folder with a business account and then move a file into that folder. I know from this link that the information is available in AppData\Dropbox\info.json

https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4584

The challenge I am facing is reading this file.

First I am not able to find any code to get the path of appdata and second there would most likely be security issues.

I want to know if this is even doable. I am very new to node.js and am not able to find much help online.

Thanks,
Arshya

Comment: I think the appData folder location is available in the system environment - maybe not directly to it, but a location very close to it, i.e. the *roaming* folder. So you should inspect the `process.env` variable from Node.

Comment: yes process.env.APPDATA has that info but wouldn't that be for the server? I want that on client's

Comment: Well, and how do you expect to write to a client's filesystem from a server application? Either you run your code on the client machine where this will work or you can give up - you cannot ask a browser to do arbitrary filesystem changes.

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to do. Can you brief us on that?

Comment: Since we are talking about Dropbox, I can refer you to their [developers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) section - they have APIs which allow you to modify contents of users' Dropbox folders. You shoud use that instead of trying to access customers' filesystem from browser.

Comment: We have an application that allows team members to add attachments. We want that when a user tries to attach any file to the application the application would actually move the file to their dropbox business account folder and update the path in the database. This is assuming everyone that has access to the app has a dropbox folder on their system which they most likely will.

Comment: @RobertRossmann - Yes I am aware of that option and I can see some code for that in the app. I am not sure why we are using this option instead. I will have more info soon on that.